# Rails - is new instance of Rails application created for every http request in nginx/passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger, instance

I have deployed a Rails app at `Engineyard` in `production` and `staging` environment. I am curious to know if every HTTP request for my app initializes new instance of my `Rails App` or not?

Comment: The shortest answer is 'no'. Not sure what the second part of your question means.

Answer (score 2):

Rails is stateless, which means each request to a Rails application has its own environment and variables that are unique to that request. So, a qualified "yes", each request starts a new instance<sup>[1]</sup> of your app; you can't determine what happened in previous requests, or other requests happening at the same time.  But, bear in mind the app will be served from a fixed set of workers.

With Rails on EY, you will be running something like thin or unicorn as the web server. This will have a defined number of workers, let's say 5. Each worker can handle only one request at a time, because that's how rails works. So if your requests take 200ms each, that means you can handle approximately 5 requests per second, for each worker. If one request takes a long time (a few seconds), that worker is not available to take any other requests. Workers are typically not created and removed on Engineyard; they are set up and run continuously until you re-deploy, though for something like Heroku, your app may not have any workers (dynos) and if there are no requests coming in it will have to spin up.

---

<sub>[1] I'm defining instance, as in, a new instance of the application class. Each model and class will be re-instantiated and the @request and @session built from scratch.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

According to what I have understood. **No, It will definitely not initialize new instance for every request**. Then again two questions might arise.

- How can multiple user simultaneously login and access my system without interference?
- Even though one user takes up too much processing time, how is another user able to access other features.

Answer to the first question is that HTTP is stateless, everything is stored in session, which is in cookie, which is in client machine and not in server. So when you send a HTTP request for a logged in user, browser actually sends the HTTP request with the required credentials/user information from clients cookies to the server without the user knowing it. Multiple requests are just queued and served accordingly. Since our server are very very fast, I feel its just processing instantly.

For the second query, your might might be concurrency. The server you are using (nginx, passenger) has the capacity to serve multiple request at same time. Even if our server might be busy for a particular user(Lets say for video processing), it might serve another request through another thread so that multiple user can simultaneously access our system.